# Responsive Navbar (Collapsing)

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(128,128,128, 0.8);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transition: top 0.5s;}

.right-navbar {
    float: right;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #FFA500;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child){
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}

nav img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Sunshine</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/home/kriti/Desktop/Project/navigation.css">
</head>
<body>
 <!--Start of Navigation-->
 <nav>
  <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
   <div class="navbar-logo">
    <a href="#">
     <img src="/home/kriti/Desktop/Project/logo-1.png" alt="Sunshine" style="height: 13px;">
    </a>
   </div>
   <div class="right-navbar">
    <a href="#"> Home</a>
    <a href="#Contact">Our Products</a>
    <a href="#">Our Partners</a>
    <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
   </div>
  </div>
  <img src="/home/kriti/Desktop/Project/cover2.jpg" class="red">
 </nav>
 <!--Menu Button Script-->
 <script>
  function myFunction() {
   var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
   if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
   } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
   }
  }
 </script>
 <!--smooth scrolling of page when clicked on links-->
 <script type="text/javascript">
    document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]').forEach(anchor => {
     anchor.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      document.querySelector(this.getAttribute('href')).scrollIntoView({
       behavior: 'smooth'
      });
     });
    });
 </script>
 <!--hide nav-bar when scrolling down-->
   <script>
    var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
    window.onscroll = function() {
     var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
     if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
      document.getElementById("myTopnav").style.top = "0";
     } else {
      document.getElementById("myTopnav").style.top = "-50px";
     }
     prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
    }
   </script>
 <!--End of Naigation-->
</body>
</html>
```

Hi, guys I am learning html, css and java script. I was trying to create a Navbar which gives you a drop-down menu when viewed in a lower resolution also it's a fixed top navbar. I was able to create the same, however when we  scroll down the page and then try to open a dropdown button we will have to scroll all the way up to select another option. Can someone please help me out how can we select the option half way of the page. I also tried to keep the color of the link orange when clicked on link by using .active but was not able to do the same

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, 
[How To Create a Scroll To Top Button](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_scroll_to_top.asp)